# dictionary throwing random digits at the output

Tags: java

The Output of this problem is throwing some random digits at the end and I can't seem to figure it out.
I am trying to insert into the dictionary by ID and Name. But, when I use find function, it seems like it is not working properly. I tried reading this file by StringTokenizer method and results are same.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

text file e1.txt has only two lines:

5,rockey,4 Palomino Dr

6,James,86 norvay

---

output I get this is below:

Payroll@15db9742<--- This is a problem

Payroll@15db9742

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    UALdictionary<Integer,Payroll> idd=new UALdictionary<Integer,Payroll>();
    UALdictionary<String,Payroll>nameD=new UALdictionary<String,Payroll>();
    //Scanner cheese= new Scanner(new File("employee.txt"));

    //FileReader file = new FileReader("e1.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("e1.txt"));

    //Scanner ch =new Scanner(new File("e1.txt"));
    String line = null;
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {


        //StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ch.nextLine(), ",");

        //System.out.println("line");
        String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");
        int iD= Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[0]);
        String name = lineSplit[1];
        String addr= lineSplit[2];

        Payroll py = new Payroll(iD,name,addr);

        idd.insert(py.getID(), py);
        nameD.insert(py.getname(), py);

    }
    idd.toString();

    System.out.println(idd.find(5));
    System.out.println(nameD.find("rockey"));
    }
}
/** A simple payroll entry with ID, name, address fields */
class Payroll {
private Integer ID;
private String name;
private String address;
/** Constructor */
Payroll(int inID, String inname, String inaddr) {
ID = inID;
name = inname;
address = inaddr;
}
/** Data member access functions */
public Integer getID() { return ID; }
public String getname() { return name; }
public String getaddr() { return address; }
}
```

Comment: You need to override `toString` in your `Payroll` type. There's nothing random about the string you're getting, as you'll see if you read the Javadocs for `Object#toString`.

Comment: @LewBloch, I have update the code again with payroll class to give you guys better idea what is in there.

Comment: Look at this http://www.java2novice.com/java_interview_questions/object_methods/ all Classes without exception extends from Object (Except Object itself)

Comment: And yet, @calo, you still have not overridden `Payroll#toString`.

Answer (score 0):

Java - toString() Method

Description

The method is used to get a String object representing the value of the Number Object.

Syntax

Following are all the variants of this method −

String toString()

In other words, overrite the method toString in your class Payroll so you can have a diferent thing =)

Comment: There is no toString method in Payroll class. I have updated the code again and added my payroll class in there for you to see.

Comment: Yes there is =) remember something, all classes extends from Object, so yes you have that method you can write in your class @Override look at this http://www.java2novice.com/java_interview_questions/object_methods/

Comment: Yes @calo, we know that you haven't overridden `toString`. Have you noticed that people are recommending that you do so?